# I need create a new folder when visiting new users into my website using thier ip - php

Tags: php, http, ip, working-directory, create-directory

I need create folders to all users who visiting my website using their ip address. the folder name should be "user_ipaddress". so i have this kind of code. it's creates this kind of folders "user_1" and "user_127001". so is this right way to create new folder to individual user. or not.? thank you.

```
public function getRealIpAddr(){

    //whether ip is from the share internet  
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {  

        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];  

    }  
    //whether ip is from the proxy  
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) { 

                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];  
    }  
        //whether ip is from the remote address  
    else{  
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
    }  
    $ip = str_replace(array(":","."), "", $ip);
    return $ip;  

}

public function createDir($ip){

    $file_name = "../data/user_" . $ip;

    if(file_exists($file_name)){

        return $file_name;

    }else{
        
        mkdir($file_name);
        return $file_name;
    }
}

$ip = $this->getRealIpAddr();

createDir($ip);
```

Comment: You can use is_dir ; [is_dir doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php)

Comment: "is this right way to create new folder". Does it work or not?

Comment: this is work. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Checked this on online web server it's working perfectly. thank you

```
public function getRealIpAddr(){

//whether ip is from the share internet  
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {  

    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];  

}  
//whether ip is from the proxy  
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) { 

            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];  
}  
    //whether ip is from the remote address  
else{  
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
}  
$ip = str_replace(array(":","."), "", $ip);
return $ip;  

}

public function createDir($ip){

$file_name = "../data/user_" . $ip;

if(file_exists($file_name)){

    return $file_name;

}else{
    
    mkdir($file_name);
    return $file_name;
}
}

$ip = $this->getRealIpAddr();

createDir($ip);
```